# RestKit: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = "prop"; desired type = TypeA; given type = TypeA;

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am refactoring the latest version of my App to use RestKit.

And when parsing the JSON data I have got, I ran into the following error:

**'Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = “business”; desired type = Business; given type = Business;**

The error happened after I have

1. Successfully posted an object
2. Successfully got my feedback JSON

And the error popped up parsed most of the JSON and ready to set relationship between the objects passed in JSON.

The JSON I sent (this is for login):

```
{
    "pass":"1234",
    "id":0,
    "login":"awesome_dude",
    "tier":0
}
```

The Dictionary I have got back:

```
{
    business = 2;
    email = "<null>";
    firstName = "<null>";
    id = 36;
    lastName = "<null>";
    login = "<null>";
    pass = "<null>";
    phoneNumber = "<null>";
    sessionId = B0F4E25AF15639D09E49BB9A1F179847;
    tier = 0;
}
```

Basically I just got my user ID, session ID and the business ID which my user account is tied to.

However, the **User** object is defined slightly differently in **CoreData Model**.

The difference is in **"business"**. In JSON communication, it is just a business ID. But in my local **CoreData Model** it is a **Relation** to a full **Business Object**.

If we write the CoreData Entity Definition **in Dictionary**, it's more like:

```
{
    business = {
        address = "addr";
        category = 2;
        email = "company@email.com";
        id = 2;
        name = @"Acme";
        phoneNumber = @"911";
        postalCode = @"98105";
        .........
    }

    email = "myemail@company.com";
    firstName = "James";
    id = 36;
    lastName = "Bond";
    login = "awesome_guy";
    pass = "42";
    phoneNumber = "911";
    sessionId = B0F4E25AF15639D09E49BB9A1F179847;
    tier = 0;
}
```

Because of this, this is how I configured my mappings for User and Business:

```
/* ===============================
 * ====Business Object Mapping====
 * ==============================*/

RKEntityMapping* businessObjectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Business" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];

[businessObjectMapping setPerformKeyValueValidation:NO];

NSDictionary *businessObjectMappingDict = @{
                                        @"id":@"id",
                                        @"name":@"name",
                                        @"address":@"address",
                                        @"category":@"category",
                                        @"email":@"email",
                                        @"integration":@"integration",
                                        @"phoneNumber":@"phoneNumber",
                                        @"postalCode":@"postalCode",
                                        };
businessObjectMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

[businessObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:businessObjectMappingDict];
```

This is how I configured mapping for User:

```
 /* ===========================
 * ====User Object Mapping====
 * ==========================*/

RKEntityMapping* userObjectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];

NSDictionary *userObjectMappingDict = @{
                                    @"id":@"id",
                                    @"login":@"login",
                                    @"firstName":@"firstName",
                                    @"lastName":@"lastName",
                                    @"phoneNumber":@"phoneNumber",
                                    @"email":@"email",
                                    @"tier":@"tier",
                                    @"sessionId":@"sessionId",
                                    @"pass":@"password"
                                    };

userObjectMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

[userObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:userObjectMappingDict];

RKEntityMapping* userBusinessMapping =  [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Business" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
[userBusinessMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"business":@"id"}]; // Nil Key path

[userObjectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"business" withMapping:userBusinessMapping]];

[userObjectMapping setPerformKeyValueValidation:NO];
```

And of course I have registered User Mapping for the call:

```
/*******************************************************************
 * Object Mapping Registration                                     *
 *******************************************************************/

/* Consult API Doc for calls */
// Only used called included

[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[

......

 [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userObjectMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                         pathPattern:@"login" keyPath:nil
                                         statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
......
]];
```

FYI, I am using **Mogenerator** to generate MO files, if that matters.

And of course I have specified the classes for entities.

This error is basically saying that **"You gave me what I want, so you are wrong"**. It looks more like a CoreData error than a RestKit error.

Helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually because I have used the incorrect MOC, more specifically a different CoreData stack to insert the object.

What I used:

```
[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]
```

What I should use:

```
[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext
```

Using the latter solved the problem instantly!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the RestKit mapping you're providing because you're trying to do everything in one response descriptor (treating it like the destination is an array, not a relationship).

So, you need to break your mapping into 2 response descriptors. 1 for the user and 1 for the business. Then you need to use foreign key mapping to connect the 2 objects. This means adding the business id to the user object as a transient attribute and using:

```
[userObjectMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"business" connectedBy:@{ @"businessId": @"businessId" }];
```

Note that I have specified `businessId`, because your managed objects shouldn't really have `id` attributes so you should change to `userId` and `businessId`.